How to i get rid of the extra stuff at the to?
Hi I've been writing a PowerShell script that uses the Winget CLI tool but whenever I'm trying to use it in the way below this is the output that I keep getting when really what I want is the output that Powershell or CMD will give me if I just put it in normally

My Script
$AppsToUpdate1 = Start-Job { winget upgrade }
$AppsToUpdate2 = Wait-Job $AppsToUpdate1 | Out-Null; Receive-Job $AppsToUpdate1

Write-Output $AppsToUpdate2```

The output

   -
   \
   |
   /
   /
   /
   /
   -
   \
   |


   -

No installed package found matching input criteria.

The following packages have an upgrade available, but require explicit targeting for upgrade:
Name    Id              Version  Available Source
-------------------------------------------------
Discord Discord.Discord 1.0.9003 1.0.9156  winget


The output i want/CMD and PS will give
No installed package found matching input criteria.

The following packages have an upgrade available, but require explicit targeting for upgrade:
Name    Id              Version  Available Source
-------------------------------------------------
Discord Discord.Discord 1.0.9003 1.0.9156  winget


Try winget upgrade --disable-interactivity instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/

@MisterSmith, while you would expect that to help, it doesn't, unfortunately. Arguably, winget.exe should automatically disable any progress display when it finds its stdout redirected (i.e. when not printing to a terminal).



What you're seeing is an artifact of the progress display that winget.exe emits.

Unfortunately, as of v1.8.1911 of winget.exe, there appears to be no way to prevent these artifacts when you capture the output, as invariably happens when you use Start-Job, for instance: neither --silent (-h) nor --disable-interactivity help, as these options appear to relate to interactive prompting only.

Arguably, winget.exe itself should detect when its output is being captured - as opposed to printing to the display (console aka. terminal) - and then not show progress information.




Solution options:

Either: Filter out the progress information from the captured output after the fact, as follows:
winget upgrade | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s+[-/\|\s]+$|^$' }


Or: Use the Microsoft.WinGet.Client module instead, which is generally preferable, as it enables robust, object-based processing, without any progress display (there is currently none) getting in the way:

Install it as follows, for example:
 Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser Microsoft.WinGet.Client


Then use the following command:
 Get-WinGetPackage | Where-Object IsUpdateAvailable


Caveat:

The above is not the exact equivalent of winget upgrade in that it   (a) invariably implies --include-unknown and (b) lacks support for --include-pinned - see GitHub issue #4375 for details.





